# VBA Pivot Table Errors

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, pivot

I'm trying to make an Excel worksheet more readable and easier for me to work with by writing user defined functions
I'm trying to convert a formula like this,

```
=If(IsErr(GetPivotData(Pivot Look up information here)),0,GetPivotData(Pivot Look up information here))
```

With a vba code

```
pt.GetPivotData(Pivot Look up information here)
```

I'm having trouble detecting problems with the lookup query in VBA. In the above formula this is handled with the IsErr function. I've tried using IsError(pt.GetPivotData(Pivot lookup information here)), but the program crashes with Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error. I get this same error when I call the function from a sub without the IsError.

How can I get VBA to detect these errors?

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is you can't. The VBA editor will not tell you there are mistakes and the compiler will not either if the syntax is right just as you can drill through your hand if you are careless. You are using the tool right to pierce holes but not in the proper material.

This type of error occurs when you are accessing objects that do not exist or objects that are not set. Use the debugger to step through each line and use the `local variables` windows and maybe even the `execution` window and a few spies here and there to detect what went wrong.

Really, I don't think we can help much more than that without more code and context.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to detect pivot table entries that do not exist

Comment: Please edit your initial post with a question that is fit for a FAQ and add any relevant code (but not more).